# How to use restrict method? telegram-bot

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram, telegram-bot

I am currently making a telegram bot with google script(javascript), and I want to add a function that every time a user join the group,the bot can restrict the user automatically, and here is the details of how you can do it https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#restrictchatmember, what issue me is I don't understand `ChatPermisson` part,

below is the code:

```
var ChatPermissions = {
  "can_send_messages": false,
  "can_send_media_messages": false,
  "can_send_other_messages": false,
  "can_add_web_page_previews": false,
  "can_send_polls": false,
  "can_change_info": false,
  "can_invite_users": false,
  "can_pin_messages": false
}
var restrict = {
  "method": "restrictChatMember",
  "chat_id": String(e.message.chat.id),
  "user_id": userid,
  "permissions": JSON.stringify(ChatPermissions)
}
start(restrict);
```

this is what I do in my code, but it seems that this is not how you do it, anyone know?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests)? And what does `start` do?

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't say it clearly, I had already set up the webhook to google script,so every time telegram bot get update, it will send the update json to my app script, and 'start' is a function I wrote in my code, it will do a http request by sending the 'restrict' json to telegram server.   And now I knew how to get chatid and userid,  but I don't understand how to send the 'restrict' with 'permission' correctly, like I need to define chatpermission as a json or array type or sth else?

Comment: I think the way you've done is correct.  If there's a problem, Provide [mcve]  preferably in a new question.